# Android Studio debugger does not show local variables with JackOptions enable

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-debug, android-studio-2.1, jack-compiler

After I enable JackOptions in build.gradle and use java version 1.8, Android studio debugger crashed. It does not show local variables.Is this the side effect of JackOptions? Any suggestions?

My Android Stdudio version is 2.1.2, buildtoolsversion is 24.0.0.

disable JackOptions
[image]

enable JackOptions

```
android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    jackOptions { enabled true }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

[image]